# Radio and inbound Calls Volumes Can be set separately?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, volume-control

On Samsung Galaxy 2 is there a way to set volumes for the radio and incoming calls separately from each other? What's too laud for the radio (for me anything above 3) is not loud enough for the incoming calls, which results in me missing calls.

Comment: Normally, FM radio should use Media volume and not Call volume. Are you sure you have different volumes set for call and media and they are not linked with each other?

Comment: positive. I missed quite a number of calls because of when I'm listening to the radio I set volume to low and always forget to restore it back after.

Comment: Actually it's easy to confirm it - the volume regulator on the phone itself changes the volume of the radio, equally the software volume regulator on the radio changes the main volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything else fails (and your comment above says you cannot set the volumes separately as needed), you could take a look at [Volume Ace](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.braincrash.volumeacefree), which not only allows you to set all volumes separately<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmepw.jpg)</sup>, but even lets you create profiles<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxKw9.png)</sup> switchable via widgets<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbRxz.jpg)</sup>:

[image: Volume Ace Rockers] [image: Volume Ace Widgets] [image: Volume Ace Profiles]

This enables you to always have the right volume settings according to the situation.

Comment: great app, loving it!